# Convert a CanvasRenderingContext variable for a javascript API

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have a javascript API that takes a canvas context as an argument

The following

```
var context2dJs = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(canvas.getContext('2d'));
```

throws `Exception: Uncaught Error: object must be an Node, ArrayBuffer, Blob, ImageData, or IDBKeyRange`

but the following works

```
var context2dJs = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(canvas).callMethod('getContext', ['2d']);
```

However, designing a wrapper around this API, I'd like the dart API to be similar and have a `CanvasRenderingContext` parameter. How can I convert such dart parameter to its javascript equivalent?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get directly the JsObject corresponding to a `CanvasRenderingContext`. Please file an issue at http://dartbug.com